# sqlite3 executemany DELETE runs slow

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have a database with around 12 million entries which i need to update daily. I have an update dataset with around 10k ids which i need to remove from the database and then insert the update dataset.

```
query_delete_orders = ("""DELETE FROM rawdata WHERE orderid = ?""")
list_orderids = [(x,) for x in data_update["orderid"].unique()]
cursor.executemany(query_delete_orders, list_orderids)
```

I can't use UPDATE becuase "orderid" is not a primary key and has more than 1 row in the database.
The execution of this code takes more than an hour... Does anyone have suggestions on how to improve performance?

Comment: Do you have an index on `orderid`?

Comment: yes i do. you think reindexing is the problem? If so, do you have an idea how to avoid that?